# What vegan oils or fats are solid at room temperature?

Tags: fats

What vegan oils or fats are solid at room temperature?

Is coconut oil the only thing?

Answer (score 1):

Coconut oil is a liquid to me here in Chennai all year round ;)

Cocoa butter is the only solid fat I use in the kitchen. I use shea butter but only as a moisturiser, not for eating. Both of them melt somewhere in the mid 30s Celsius.